# How can I ensure that my horizontal scrollbar resets to 'scrollLeft = 0' when generating an OpenLayers overlay?

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers, overlay

If I use the button (.overlay-closer) to close the current overlay, I have it set to reset the scrollLeft to 0, but if I just click on a new OpenLayers feature to generate a replacement overlay it will keep the current horizontal scroll position.

```
const popup = new Overlay({
  element: document.getElementById('popup-container'),
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  },
})

map.addOverlay(popup)

const overlayCloser = document.querySelector('.overlay-closer')
overlayCloser.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const contentElement = popup.getElement().querySelector('#popup-content');
  contentElement.scrollLeft = 0;
})


<div id="popup-container" class="ol-popup overlay-container"> 
  <div class="popup-header">
    <h5 class="popup-title">Details</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm overlay-closer">X</button>
  </div>
  <div id="popup-content"></div>
</div>


#popup-content {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

First time posting so my apologies if my formatting is not to standard. Thanks!

I have tried `popup.on('change', function() {` as well as `on('open/close')`, but those don't seem to change anything.

```
popup.on('change', function() {
  const contentElement = popup.getElement().querySelector('#popup-content');
  contentElement.scrollLeft = 0;
})
```

Comment: Use the `change:position` event (or set `scrollLeft` immediately bwfore calling `setPosition()`)

Comment: That resolved my issue -- thank you! How can I mark this as the answer?